# Improve serial building of a string with openMP {Copeland-Erdős constant}

Tags: string, c++11, math, substring, openmp

I'm building a program to find substrings of Copeland-Erdős constant in C++11

[Copeland-Erdős constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Copeland-ErdosConstant.html) is a string with all primes in order:
2,3,5,7,11,13… → 23571113…

I need to check if a substring given is inside that constant, and do it in a quick way.

By the moment I've build a serial program using Miller Rabin function for checking if the numbers generated by a counter are primes or not and add to the main string (constant). To find [8th Marsene Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number)) (2<sup>31</sup>-1) the program spends 8 minutes.

And then, I use find to check if the substring given is in the constant and the position where it starts.

**PROBLEMS:**

I use serial programming. I start at 0 and check if all numbers are prime to add them or not... I don't know if there is any other way to do it. The substring can be a mix of primes. ex: 1..{1131}..7 (substring of 11,13,17)

Do you have any proposal to improve the program execution time by using OpenMP?

I want to calculate 9th Mersene Number in "human time". I've spend more than one day and it doesn't find it (well, arrive to the number).

```
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313
```

***Main.cpp***

```
while (found == -1 && lastNumber < LIMIT)   //while not found & not pass our limit
{
    //I generate at least a string with double size of the input (llargada)
    for (lastNumber; primers.length() <= 2*llargada; lastNumber++){
        if (is_prime_mr(lastNumber))
            primers += to_string(lastNumber);    //if prime, we add it to the main string
    }
    found = primers.find(sequencia);    //search substring and keep position
    if (found == string::npos){         //if not found
        indexOfZero += primers.length()/2;      //keep IndexOfZero, the position of string in global constant
        primers.erase(0,primers.length()/2);     //delete first middle part of calculated string
    }
}

if (found != -1){
    cout << "FOUNDED!" << endl;
    cout << "POS: " << indexOfZero << " + " << found << " = " << indexOfZero+found << endl;} //that give us the real position of the substring in the main string
    //although we only spend 2*inputString.size() memory
    else
        cout << "NOT FOUND" << endl;
```

Comment: first optimize your serial code, then proceed to parallelize it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to 
Computational Science http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Improving serial execution:**

For starters, you do not need to check every number to see if it's prime, but rather every odd number (except for 2). We know that no even number past two can be prime. This should cut down your execution time in half.

Also, I do not understand why you have a nested loop. You should only have to check your list once.

Also, I fear that your algorithm might not be correct. Currently, if you do not find the substring, you delete half of your string and move on. However, if you have 50 non-primes in a row, you could end up deleting the entire string except for the very last character. But what if the substring you're looking for is 3 digits and needed 2 of the previous characters? Then you've erased some of the information needed to find your solution!

Finally, you should only search for your substring if you've actually found a prime number. Otherwise, you have already searched for it last iteration and nothing has been added to your `string`.

Combining all of these ideas, you have:

```
primers = "23";
lastNumber = 3;
found = -1;
while (found == -1)
{
    lastNumber += 2;
    if (is_prime_mr(lastNumber)) {
        primers += to_string(lastNumber);        //if prime, we add it to the main string
        found = primers.find(sequencia);         //search substring and keep position
        if (found == string::npos)
            found = -1;
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, you should write your own `find` function to only check the last few digits (where few = length of your most recent concatenation to the global string `primers`). If the substring wasn't in the previous global string, there's only a few places it could pop up in your newest string. That algorithm should be `O(1)` as opposed to `O(n)`.

```
int findSub(std::string total, std::string substring, std::string lastAddition);
```

With this change your `if` statement should change to:

```
if (found != -1)
    break;
```

**Adding parallelism:**

Unfortunately, as-is, your algorithm is inherently serial because you have to iterate through all the primes one-by-one, adding them to the list in a row in order to find your answer. There's no simple OpenMP way to parallelize your algorithm.

However, you *can* take advantage of parallelism by breaking up your string into pieces and having each thread work separately. Then, the only tricky thing you have to do is consider the boundaries between the final strings to double check you haven't missed anything. Something like as follows:

```
bool globalFound = false;
bool found;
std::vector<std::string> primers;
#pragma omp parallel private(lastNumber, myFinalNumber, found, my_id, num_threads)
{
    my_id = omp_get_thread_num();
    num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    if (my_id == 0) { // first thread starts at 0... well, actually 3
        primers.resize(num_threads);
        #pragma omp barrier
        primers[my_id] = "23";
        lastNumber = 3;
    }
    else {
        // barrier needed to ensure that primers is initialized to correct size
        #pragma omp barrier
        primers[my_id] = "";
        lastNumber = (my_id/(double)num_threads)*LIMIT - 2; // figure out my starting place
        if (lastNumber % 2 == 0) // ensure I'm not even
            lastNumber++;
    }
    found = false;
    myFinalNumber = ((my_id+1)/(double)num_threads)*LIMIT - 2;

    while (!globalFound && lastNumber < myFinalNumber)
    {
        lastNumber += 2;
        if (is_prime_mr(lastNumber)) {
            primers[my_id] += to_string(lastNumber);
            found = findSub(primers[my_id], sequencia, to_string(lastNumber)); // your new version of find
            if (found) {
                #pragma omp atomic
                globalFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (!globalFound) {
    // Result was not found in any thread, so check for boundaries/endpoints
    globalFound = findVectorSubstring(primers, sequencia);
}
```

I'll let you finish this (by writing the smart `find`, `findVectorSubstring` - should only be checking for boundaries between elements of `primers`, and double checking you understand the logic of this new algorithm). Furthermore, if the arbitrary `LIMIT` that you setup turns out to be too small, you can always wrap this whole thing in a loop that searches between `i*LIMIT` and `(i+1)*LIMIT`.

Lastly, yes there will be load balancing issues. I can certainly imagine threads finding an uneven amount of prime numbers. Therefore, certain threads will be doing more work in the `find` function than others. However, a smart version of `find()` should be `O(1)` whereas `is_prime_mr()` is probably `O(n)` or `O(logn)`, so I'm assuming that the majority of the execution time will be spent in the `is_prime_mr()` function. Therefore, I do not believe the load balancing will be too bad.

Hope this helps.